# What goes into Responce in jQuery AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm sorry to add this broad question here, but I cannot seem to google it myself, I tried, and I really can't grasp the idea behind this, so here goes.
So I have a web-site that uses AJAX to login a user without full page reload. I kind of understand how AJAX works, and I'm sorry for my ignorance, but in my case:

```
$.ajax({
            url: './',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {auth: auth, login: login, pass: pass}
            success: function(res){
               // Code that checks if **res** is a specific string
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error!");
            }
```

I understand that this sends POST request to the same page with 3 parameters. What I don't understand is what specifically does it get as a responce? In my case, in `res` is the `$_SESSION` element that contains the string message.
**My question is:** how do I know what gets in the responce? If I would just `echo` something in my function, would that get in the responce? Is there like a documentation about what can be passed to the arguments of success function?
I'm really confused about this.

Comment: It depends on the server methods where form is being posted...:)

Comment: use the console panel->network in chrome Or firebug at firefox to see the response.
You also may set the post data like this: 'auth=' + auth + '&login=' + login + '&pass=' + pass

Comment: try with alert(res) in success function. what ever you write in response it will assigned to res param in success function;

Comment: @jQuery yeah, but for example, if I create 2 $_SESSION variables instead of 1 - res doesn't show anything. I assume it should be passing an array, but I could be wrong, so what happens then? When I replace $_SESSION with echo, it works. I'm sorry, maybe these tutorials are just not very good and I should just watch better ones, but.. yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "res"... or commonly "data" in most examples, is simply the reply data from your page that your posting to..

So say in the case of PHP... you yes would simply echo anything back to it.

commonly people use JSON, so with php you would create a array with all the data you want to send back and then simply do

YOUR PAGE THAT SENDS THE POST

```
<script>
    // JUST USING SUCCESS HERE ATM (Tthis does not show the full ajax command)
    // Refer to original question for full javascript
    success: function(res){
      var myData = $.parseJSON(res);
      if(myData.hasOwnProperty('name')){
          alert(myData.name);
      }
      if(myData.hasOwnProperty('object1') && myData.object1.hasOwnProperty('items')){
          alert(myData.object1.items.one);
      }
    },
</script>
```

YOUR PHP PAGE THAT RESPONDS

```
<?php
  $myResponse = array();
  $myResponse['name'] = "John Doe";
  $myResponse['number'] = 123456789;
  $myResponse['other'] = "and so on";
  $myResponse['object1'] = array();
  $myResponse['object2'] = array();

  $myResponse['object1']['name'] = "john";
  $myResponse['object1']['items'] = array();
  $myResponse['object1']['items']['one'] = "one one 1";
  $myResponse['object1']['items']['two'] = "two two 2";

  $myResponse['object2']['name'] = "jane";


  echo json_encode($myResponse);
?>
```

By using a "multidimensional" array in php, you can then treat each part of the array as a separate section/object

This might help: http://www.thecave.info/pass-a-php-array-to-javascript-as-json-using-ajax-and-json_encode/

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes more sense now. But let's say I would want to pass a couple of varibles, can I do that somehow? Or you can only pass 1 thing at a time? (So like 1 variable, or 1 array, or 1 object)

Comment: By using JSON/PHP Array... You can technically pass multiple items back at once.. Will update/edit.

Comment: Updated my answer.. Short answer, only one object/array can be returned. But you just make that a multi-object/array to handle multiple items.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it better. The only question that remains is how do you pass the data from PHP?  
I see you used `echo`, in my example, a function just sets the variable to $_SESSION. I assume you can do both, depending on if you need the data in the $_SESSION array. Are there other ways to do it? If I would just assing the information to the variable without `echo`, would that work for example etc?

Comment: This example does pass the data from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that what you "echo" is what you will retrieve in the "res",
try to see it in the console with:

```
console.log(res);
```

Or with an alert

```
alert(res);
```

Comment: Should be a comment on the original question as this does not exactly answer the main question.. More so it does not give a true example of what to send from PHP or how to deal with the response/data

Answer (score 1):

try `console.log(res);` and check the browser console

`ctrl` + `shift` + `k` (firefox)

`f12` (Chrome & IE)

Comment: Should be a comment on the original question as this does not exactly answer the main question.. More so it does not give a true example of what to send from PHP or how to deal with the response/data

Answer (score 1):

For you task I would recommend using getJSON, instead of .ajax. It's just a shorthand for the same function, but really handy.

```
$.getJSON('/ajax-get-session/login/value/pass/value', function(json){
   if (!json.error) { //check if there wasn't error on the server side
       console.log(json.session);
   } else {
       console.log(json.error);
   }
});
```

And on the server side.

```
$response = array();
try {
  $response['session'] = $_SESSION;

}
catch (e) {
  $response['error'] = e;

}

echo json_encode($response)
```

Comment: The problem with getJSON... is it only uses "GET" requests.. so if the user wants to deal with a POST situation.. They then need to use AJAX anyway.. simply ajax is the ideal function that works in all cases.. Shorthand code can cause hours of wonder..